# Pandas convert datatype of multiple columns using list

Tags: python, pandas, types

I have a pandas dataframe `df` and two lists, one containing column names `col_list` and the other describing their datatype `dtype_list` respectively. Now I can select the required columns like so:

```
col_list = ['date', 'period', 'name', 'type', 'id', 'address', 'zip', 'number']
dtype_list = ['DATETIME','DATETIME','VARCHAR','VARCHAR','NUMERIC','VARCHAR','NUMERIC','NUMERIC']
df = df[col_list]
```

But how can I specify datatype easily?

Comment: well firstly those aren't pandas datatypes they SQL - but pandas has a `select_dtypes` `df.select_dtypes('int64')` for example

Comment: @Manakin yes, will have to convert `dtype_list` values to corresponding pandas datatypes first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve it like so:

```
for i, item in enumerate(dtype_list):
    if item=='DATETIME':
        dtype_list[i] = 'datetime64'
    elif item=='NUMERIC':
        dtype_list[i] = 'int'
    else:
        dtype_list[i] = 'object'
dtype_dict = {col_list[i]: dtype_list[i] for i in range(len(col_list))}
df = df[col_list]
df = df.astype(dtype_dict)
```